# Return rows from multiple requests with datatable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, request, oledb, oraclecommand

If I have two or more queries in the same command:

```
Using myCommand As New OracleCommand(
"select value from table where id between 1 and 3;" & 
"select value1 from table where id = 1000", DBSettings.GetConnection())
```

and I have `DataTable` which select the values from the first request

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
dt.Load(myCommand.ExecuteReader)

value1 = dt.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString().Trim()
value2 = dt.Rows(1).Item(0).ToString().Trim()
value3 = dt.Rows(2).Item(0).ToString().Trim()
```

Can I get values throuth DataTable from second request? Is it possible, that my values get the rows from the following requests?

I do not want to create a a lot of commands and DataTable, because I have a lot of commands and the values that I need to initialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a [UNION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm). It will combine two query into one result set.

```
select value from table where id between 1 and 3
UNION
select value1 from table where id = 1000;
```

Here's the same query with the new information from your question

```
SELECT SYSPARM_VAL2 FROM SMS_PARM WHERE SYSPARM_ID BETWEEN 9900029 AND 9900033
UNION
SELECT SYSPARM_VAL4 FROM SMS_PARM WHERE SYSPARM_ID = 9900030;
```

Comment: How do you know what table this is coming from?

Comment: In SQL the UNION clause combines the results of two SQL queries into a single table of all matching rows. The two queries must result in the same number of columns and compatible data types in order to unite. => I have not same numbers of columns

Comment: @EmmaW. you should show the proper queries within your question so we know what we are working with. the_lotus was in a good position to suggest UNION as that would fit your example but obviously this does not meet your needs as suggested in your comment.